# Error handling considerations

Tags: c++, coding-style, exceptions, paradigms

**The problem:**

Since long time, I am worried about the `exceptions` mechanism, because I feel it does not really resolve what it should.

CLAIM: There are long debates outside about this topic, and most of them struggle at comparing `exceptions` vs returning an error code. This is definitively not the topic here.

Trying to define an error, I would agree with CppCoreGuidelines, from Bjarne Stroustrup & Herb Sutter

> **An error means that the function cannot achieve its advertised purpose**

CLAIM: The `exception` mechanism is a language semantic for handling errors.

CLAIM: To me, there is "no excuse" to a function for not achieving a task: Either we wrongly defined pre/post conditions so the function cannot ensure results, or some specific exceptional case is not considered important enough for spending time in developing a solution. Considering that, IMO, the difference between normal code and error code handling is (before implementation) a very subjective line.

CLAIM: Using exceptions to indicate when a pre or post condition is not keep is another purpose of the `exception` mechanism, mainly for debugging purpose. I do not target this usage of `exceptions` here.

In many books, tutorials and other sources, they tend to show error handling as a quite objective science, that is solved with `exceptions` and you just need to `catch` them for having a robust software, able to recover from any situation. But my several years as a developer make me to see the problem from a different approach:

- Programmers tends to simplify their task by throwing exceptions when the specific case seem too rare to be implemented carefully. Typical cases of this are: out of memory issues, disk full issues, corrupted file issues, etc. This might be sufficient, but is not always decided from an architectural level.
- Programmers tends not reading carefully documentation about exceptions in libraries, and are usually not aware of which and when a function throws. Furthermore, even when they know, they don't really manage them.
- Programmers tends not catching exceptions early enough, and when they do, it is mostly to log and throw further. (refer to first point).

This has two consequences:

1. Errors happening frequently are detected early in development and debugged (which is good).
2. Rare exceptions are not managed and make the system to crash (with a nice log message) at the user home. Some times the error is reported, or not even.

Considering that, IMO the main purpose of an error mechanism should be:

1. Make visible in code where some specific case is not managed.
2. Communicate the issue runtime to related code (at least the caller) when this situation happens.
3. Provides recovery mechanisms

The main flaw of the `exception` semantic as an error handling mechanism is IMO: it is easy to see where a `throw` is in the source code, but absolutely not evident to know if a specific function could throw by looking at the declaration. This bring all the problem that I introduced above.

> The language do not enforce and check the error code as strictly as it make for other aspects of the language (e.g. strong types of variables)

**A try for solution**

In the intention of improving this, I developed a very simple error handling system, which tries to put the error handling at the same level of importance than the normal code.

The idea is:

- Each (relevant) function receive a reference to a `success` very light object, and may set it to an error status in case. The object is very light until a error with text is saved.
- A function is encouraged to skip its task if the object provided contain already an error.
- An error must never be override.

The full design obviously consider thoroughly each aspect (about 10 pages), also how to apply it to OOP.

Example of the `Success` class:

```
class Success
{
public:
    enum SuccessStatus
    {
        ok = 0,             // All is fine
        error = 1,          // Any error has been reached
        uninitialized = 2,  // Initialization is required
        finished = 3,       // This object already performed its task and is not useful anymore
        unimplemented = 4,  // This feature is not implemented already
    };

    Success(){}
    Success( const Success& v);
    virtual ~Success() = default;
    virtual Success& operator= (const Success& v);

    // Comparators
    virtual bool operator==( const Success& s)const { return (this->status==s.status && this->stateStr==s.stateStr);}
    virtual bool operator!=( const Success& s)const { return (this->status!=s.status || this->stateStr==s.stateStr);}

    // Retrieve if the status is not "ok"
    virtual bool operator!() const { return status!=ok;}

    // Retrieve if the status is "ok"
    operator bool() const { return status==ok;}

    // Set a new status
    virtual Success& set( SuccessStatus status, std::string msg="");
    virtual void reset();

    virtual std::string toString() const{ return stateStr;}
    virtual SuccessStatus getStatus() const { return status; }
    virtual operator SuccessStatus() const { return status; }

private:
    std::string stateStr;
    SuccessStatus status = Success::ok;
};
```

Usage:

```
double mySqrt( Success& s, double v)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    if (!s) ; // do nothing
    else if (v<0.0) s.set(Error, "Square root require non-negative input.");
    else result = std::sqrt(v);
    return result;
}

Success s;
mySqrt(s, 144.0);
otherStuff(s);
saveStuff(s);
if (s) /*All is good*/;
else cout << s << endl;
```

I used that in many of my (own) code and it force the programmer (me) to think further about possible exceptional cases and how to solve them (good). However, it has a learning curve and don't integrate well with code that do now use it.

**The question**

I would like to understand better the implications of using such a paradigm in a project:

- Is the premise to the problem correct? or Did I missed something relevant?
- Is the solution a good architectural idea? or the price is too high?

---

EDIT:

Comparison between methods:

```
//Exceptions:

    // Incorrect
    File f = open("text.txt"); // Could throw but nothing tell it! Will crash
    save(f);

    // Correct
    File f;
    try
    {
        f = open("text.txt");
        save(f);
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        // do something 
    }

//Error code (mixed):

    // Incorrect
    File f = open("text.txt"); //Nothing tell you it may fail! Will crash
    save(f);

    // Correct
    File f = open("text.txt");
    if (f) save(f);

//Error code (pure);

    // Incorrect
    File f;
    open(f, "text.txt"); //Easy to forget the return value! will crash
    save(f);

    //Correct
    File f;
    Error er = open(f, "text.txt");
    if (!er) save(f);

//Success mechanism:

    Success s;
    File f;
    open(s, "text.txt");
    save(s, f); //s cannot be avoided, will never crash.
    if (s) ... //optional. If you created s, you probably don't forget it.
```

Comment: Upvoted for "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear", not because I agree: I think quite some of the thoughts are misguided. (Details may follow in an answer.)

Comment: Absolutely, I understand and agree on that! It is the purpose of this question to get criticized. And the score of the question to indicate good/bad questions, not that the OP is right.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your main gripe about exceptions is that people can ignore it (in c++) instead of handling them. However, your Success construct has the same flaw by design. Like exceptions, they'll just ignore it. Even worse: it's more verbose, leads to cascading returns, and you can't even "catch" it upstream.

Comment: Is not that you can ignore them, is that you don't see them: `vect.push_back(2)` should you catch around that? (yes but you don't know).  The idea is to make the need of error catch explicit/obvious (which is not in exceptions/error code). And you can upstream it: just use the provided `s`. You can also stream it down or forward, which is not the case of exceptions/error_codes

Comment: Why not just use something like monads? They make your errors implicit but they won't be silent during run. Actually, the first thing I thought when looking at your code was "monads, nice". Have a look at them.

Comment: The main reason I like exceptions is they allow you to catch all unexpected errors from a given block of code and handle them consistently. Yes, there is no good reason the code shouldn't perform its task - "there was a bug" is a bad reason *but it still happens*, and when it happens you want to log the cause and display a message, or retry. (I have some code that does a complex, restartable interaction with a remote system; should the remote system go down, I want to log it and retry from the beginning)

Comment: Important data: Phone mms sending failure rate is about 11% due to network reliability. But failing to send an mms is not an indication bug. It's an exceptional case.

Comment: "[...] or some specific exceptional case is not considered important enough for spending time in developing a solution", does this assume all exceptional cases can be known?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga: I would put it as sort of a meta-target. Should we try it? yes. Is it achievable? Probably not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Error-handling** is perhaps the hardest portion of a program.

In general, realizing that there is an error condition is easy; however signalling it in a way that cannot be circumvented and handling it appropriately (see [Abrahams' Exception Safety levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)) is really hard.

In C, signalling errors is done by a return code, which is isomorphic to your solution.

C++ introduced exceptions because of the *short-coming* of such an approach; namely, it only works if callers remember to check whether an error occurred or not and fails apart horribly otherwise. Whenever you find yourself saying "It's OK as long as every time..." you have a problem; humans are not that meticulous, even when they care.

The problem, however, is that exceptions have their own issues. Namely, invisible/hidden control flow. This was intended: hiding the error case so that the logic of the code is not obfuscated by the error handling boilerplate. It makes the "happy path" much clearer (and fast!), at the cost of making the error paths nigh inscrutable.

---

I find it interesting to look at how other languages approach the issue:

- Java has checked exceptions (and unchecked ones),
- Go uses error codes/panics,
- Rust uses [sum types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html)/panics).
- FP languages in general.

C++ used to have some form of checked exceptions, you may have noticed it has been deprecated and simplified toward a basic `noexcept(<bool>)` instead: either a function is declared to possibly throw, or it's declared never to. Checked exceptions are somewhat problematic in that they lack extensibility, which can cause awkward mappings/nesting. And convoluted exception hierarchies (one of the prime use cases of virtual inheritance is exceptions...).

In contrast, Go and Rust take the approach that:

- errors should be signaled in band,
- exception should be used for really exceptional situations.

The latter is rather evident in that (1) they name their exceptions *panics* and (2) there is no type hierarchy/complicated clause here. The language does not offer facilities to inspect the content of a "panic": no type hierarchy, no user-defined content, just a "oops, things went so wrong there's no possible recovery".

This effectively encourages users to use proper error handling, whilst still leaving an easy way to bail out in exceptional situations (such as: "wait, I haven't implement that yet!").

Of course, the Go approach unfortunately is much like yours in that you can easily forget to check the error...

... the Rust approach however is mostly centered around two types:

- `Option`, which is similar to `std::optional`,
- [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), which is a two possibilities variant: Ok and Err.

this is much neater because there is no opportunity for accidentally using a result without having checked for success: if you do, the program panics.

---

FP languages form their error handling in constructs which can be split in three layers:
  - Functor
  - Applicative / Alternative
  - Monads / Alternative

Let's have a look at Haskell's `Functor` typeclass:

```
class Functor m where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

First of all, typeclasses are somewhat similar but not equal to interfaces. Haskell's function signatures look a bit scary on a first look. But let's decipher them. The function `fmap` takes a function as first parameter which is somewhat similar to `std::function<a,b>`. The next thing is an `m a`. You can imagine `m` as something like `std::vector` and `m a` as something like `std::vector<a>`. But the difference is, that `m a` doesn't say it has to be explicitly `std:vector`. So it could be a `std::option`, too. By telling the language that we have an instance for the typeclass `Functor` for a specific type like `std::vector` or `std::option`, we can use the function `fmap` for that type. The same must be done for the typeclasses `Applicative`, `Alternative` and `Monad` which allows you to do stateful, possible failing computations. The `Alternative` typeclass implements error recovery abstractions. By that you can say something like `a <|> b` meaning it's either term `a` or term `b`. If neither of both computations succeed, it's still an error.

Let's have a look at Haskell's `Maybe` type.

```
data Maybe a
  = Nothing
  | Just a
```

This means, that where you expect a `Maybe a`, you get either `Nothing` or `Just a`. When looking at `fmap` from above, an implementation could look like

```
fmap f m = case m of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just a -> Just (f a)
```

The `case ... of` expression is called pattern matching and resembles what is known in the OOP world as `visitor pattern`. Imagine the line `case m of` as `m.apply(...)` and the dots is the instantiation of a class implementing the dispatch functions. The lines below the `case ... of` expression are the respective dispatch functions bringing the fields of the class directly in scope by name. In the `Nothing` branch we create `Nothing` and in the `Just a` branch we name our only value `a` and create another `Just ...` with the transformation function `f` applied to `a`. Read it as: `new Just(f(a))`.

This can now handle erroneous computations while abstracting the actual error checks away. There exist implementations for the other interfaces which makes this kind of computations very powerful. Actually, `Maybe` is the inspiration for Rust's `Option`-Type.

---

I would there encourage you to rework your `Success` class toward a `Result` instead. Alexandrescu actually proposed something really close, called `expected<T>`, for which standard proposals [were made](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf).

I will stick to the Rust naming and API simply because... it's documented and works. Of course, Rust has a nifty `?` suffix operator which would make the code much sweeter; in C++, we'll use the `TRY` macro and GCC's [statements expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) to emulate it.

```
template <typename E>
struct Error {
    Error(E e): error(std::move(e)) {}

    E error;
};

template <typename E>
Error<E> error(E e) { return Error<E>(std::move(e)); }

template <typename T, typename E>
struct [[nodiscard]] Result {
    template <typename U>
    Result(U u): ok(true), data(std::move(u)), error() {}

    template <typename F>
    Result(Error<F> f): ok(false), data(), error(std::move(f.error)) {}

    template <typename U, typename F>
    Result(Result<U, F> other):
        ok(other.ok), data(std::move(other.data)),  error(std::move(other.error)) {}

    bool ok = false;
    T data;
    E error;
};

#define TRY(Expr_) \
    ({ auto result = (Expr_); \
       if (!result.ok) { return result; } \
       std::move(result.data); })
```

*Note: this `Result` is a placeholder. A proper implementation would use encapsulation and a `union`. It's sufficient to get the point across however.*

Which allows me to write ([see it in action](https://ideone.com/3FB7rE)):

```
Result<double, std::string> sqrt(double x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return error("sqrt does not accept negative numbers");
    }
    return x;
}

Result<double, std::string> double_sqrt(double x) {
    auto y = TRY(sqrt(x));
    return sqrt(y);
}
```

which I find really neat:

- unlike the use of error codes (or your `Success` class), forgetting to check for errors will result in a runtime error<sup>1</sup> rather than some random behavior,
- unlike the use of exceptions, it is apparent *at the call site* which functions can fail so there's no surprise.
- with C++-2X standard, we may get `concepts` in the standard. This would make this kind of programming far more pleasuring as we could leave the choice over the error kind. E.g. with an implementation of `std::vector` as result, we could compute all possible solutions at once. Or we could choose to improve error handling, as you proposed.

<sup>1</sup> *With a properly encapsulated `Result` implementation ;)*

---

*Note: unlike exception, this lightweight `Result` does not have backtraces, which makes logging less efficient; you may find it useful to at least log the file/line number at which the error message is generated, and to generally write a rich error message. This can be compounded by capturing the file/line each time the `TRY` macro is used, essentially creating the backtrace manually, or using platform-specific code and libraries such as `libbacktrace` to list the symbols in the callstack.*

---

There is one big caveat though: existing C++ libraries, and even `std`, are based on exceptions. It'll be an uphill battle to use this style, as any 3rd party library's API must be wrapped in an adapter...

Comment: That macro looks... very wrong. I'll assume `({...})` is some gcc extension, but even so, shouldn't it be `if (!result.ok) return result;`? Your condition appears backwards and you make an unnecessary copy of the error.

Comment: @MooingDuck The answer explains that `({...})` is gcc's [statements expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs).

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks! I've fixed the condition (I'm really bad with boolean, one too many states for me) and returned `result` directly to avoid copying the error.

Comment: It should be possible to implement some kind of macro to catch an exception and return it as an error for result. Scala has a similar implementation where you `Try { ... }` some piece of code. Exceptions will be captured implicitly for you which makes wrapping those libraries straight forward and inline. Have a look at that: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html

Comment: @bash0r the newest doc is much nicer: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/util/Try.html
It's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/util/Either.html

Comment: @Reactormonk Ah yeah. That was actually the link I wanted to post. :| Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::variant` to implement the `Result` if you are using C++17. Also, to get a warning if you ignore an error, use [`[[nodiscard]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes#Standard_attributes)

Comment: @Justin: Whether to use `std::variant` or not is somewhat a matter of taste given the trade-offs around exception-handling. `[[nodiscard]]` is indeed a pure win.

Comment: You can inspect a panic in Go via recover()

Answer (score 46):

> CLAIM: The exception mechanism is a language semantic for handling errors

exceptions are a control-flow mechanism. The motivation for this control-flow mechanism, was specifically *separating* error handling from non-error handling code, in the common case that error handling is very repetitive and bears little relevance to the main part of the logic.

> CLAIM: To me, there is "no excuse" to a function for not achieving a task: Either we wrongly defined pre/post conditions so the function cannot ensure results, or some specific exceptional case is not considered important enough for spending time in developing a solution

Consider: I try to create a file. The storage device is full.

Now, this isn't a failure to define my preconditions: you can't use "there must be enough storage" as a precondition in general, because shared storage is subject to race conditions that make this impossible to satisfy.

So, should my program somehow free some space and then proceed successfully, otherwise I'm just too lazy to "develop a solution"? This seems frankly nonsensical. The "solution" to managing shared storage is *outside the scope of my program*, and allowing my program to fail gracefully, and be re-run once the user has either released some space, or added some more storage, is *fine*.

---

What your success class does is interleave error-handling very explicitly with your program logic. Every single function needs to check, before running, whether some error already occurred which means it shouldn't do anything. Every library function needs to be wrapped in another function, with one more argument (and hopefully perfect forwarding), which does exactly the same thing.

Note also that your `mySqrt` function needs to return a value *even* if it failed (or a prior function had failed). So, you're either returning a magic value (like `NaN`), or injecting an indeterminate value into your program and *hoping* nothing uses that without checking the success state you've threaded through your execution.

For correctness - and performance - it's much better to pass control back out of scope once you can't make any progress. Exceptions and C-style *explicit error checking with early return* both accomplish this.

---

For comparison, an example of your idea which really does work is the [Error monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html) in Haskell. The advantage over your system is that you write the bulk of your logic normally, and then wrap it in the monad which takes care of halting evaluation when one step fails. This way the only code touching the error-handling system directly is the code that might fail (throw an error) and the code that needs to cope with the failure (catch an exception).

I'm not sure that monad style and lazy evaluation translate well to C++ though.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, it add light to the topic.  I guess the user would disagree with `and allowing my program to fail gracefully, and be re-run` when he just lost 2h work:

Comment: Your solution means that _every_ place you might create a file, you need to prompt the user to fix the situation and retry. Then every _other_ thing that might go wrong, you also need to somehow fix locally. With exceptions, you just catch `std::exception` at the higher level of the logical operation, tell the user _"X failed because of ex.what()"_, and offer to retry the whole operation when and if they're ready.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: The "allowing to fail gracefully and be re-run" could also be implemented as `showing the Save dialog again along with an error message and allowing the user to specify an alternative location to try`. That is a graceful handling of a problem that can't typically be done from the code that detects that the first storage location is full.

Comment: @Useless Lazy evaluation has nothing to do with the use of the Error monad, as evidenced by strict evaluation languages like Rust, OCaml, and F# that all make heavy use of it.

Comment: @Useless IMO for quality software, it *does* make sense that “every place you might create a file, you need to prompt the user to fix the situation and retry”. Early programmers often went to remarkable lengths towards error-recovery, at least Knuth's TeX program is full of them. And with his “literate programming” framework he found a way to keep the error-handling in another section, so that the code remains readable and the error recovery gets written with more care (because when you're writing the error-recovery section, that is the point and the programmer tends to do a better job).

Comment: @Useless C++17 actually [includes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) the closely related Option/Maybe monad.

Comment: "There must be free space" can be a precondition *for the happy path*, but to cover all cases, the correct *post*condition for the entire operation must rather be "either there was insufficient free space or the file was created". (Because of race conditions, you can't say that there *is* insufficient free space).

Comment: @8bittree true, but using Maybe for error handling (by continuing to execute statements that will no longer do anything, and have to explicitly take a Maybe, and pattern-match the do-nothing case) reproduces the part of OP's implementation I wanted to avoid. I probably explained that poorly though.

Answer (score 15):

> I would like to understand better the implications of using such a paradigm in a project:
>
> - Is the premise to the problem correct? or Did I missed something relevant?
> - Is the solution a good architectural idea? or the price is too high?

Your approach brings some large problems into your source code:

- it relies on the client code always remembering to check the value of `s`. This is common with the *use return codes for error handling* approach, and one of the reasons that exceptions were introduced into the language: with exceptions, if you fail, you do not fail silently.
- the more code you write with this approach, the more error boilerplate code you will have to add as well, for error handling (your code is no longer minimalistic) and your maintenance effort goes up.

> But my several years as a developer make me to see the problem from a different approach:

The solutions for these problems should be approached at technical lead level or team level:

> Programmers tend to simplify their task by throwing exceptions when the specific case seem too rare to be implemented carefully. Typical cases of this are: out of memory issues, disk full issues, corrupted file issues, etc. This might be sufficient, but is not always decided from an architectural level.

If you find yourself handling every type of exception that may be thrown, all the time, then the design is not good; What errors get handled, should be decided according to the specifications for the project, not according to what devs feel like implementing.

Address by setting up automated testing, separating specification of the unit tests and implementation (have two different persons do this).

> Programmers tends not reading carefully documentation [...]
>   Furthermore, even when they know, they don't really manage them.

You will not address this by writing more code. I think your best bet is meticulously-applied code reviews.

> Programmers tends not catching exceptions early enough, and when they do, it is mostly to log and throw further. (refer to first point).

Proper error handling is hard, but less tedious with exceptions than with return values (whether they are actually returned or passed as i/o arguments).

The most tricky part of error handling is not how you receive the error, but how to make sure your application keeps a consistent state in the presence of errors.

To address this, more attention needs to be allocated to identifying and running in error conditions (more testing, more unit/integration tests, etc).

Comment: `if you fail, you do not fail silently` The point of this Success class is exactly that: it make the value visible (return code are not) and it is easy to add a log to test if an object is not checked.

Comment: If in the client code you forget to check the value of s (the `if(s)` in your example client code), how will the application runtime tell you this?

Comment: I did some test where the destructor of Success log errors if they were not printed or reset. Anyway, all the code after an error is skip, so the result is inherently correct (meaning harmless and recoverable).

Comment: All the code after an error is skipped, _if you remember to check each and every time you receive an instance as an argument_. This is what I meant by "the more code you write with this approach, the more error boilerplate code you will have to add as well". You will have to riddle your code with ifs on the success instance, and every time you forget, it's a bug. The second problem caused by forgetting to check: the code that executes until you check again, should not have been executed at all (continuing if you forget to check, corrupts your data).

Comment: I see your point and don't disagree; I actually like your inputs. But continuing this "debate", the equivalent in error-code or exceptions is a straight crash, while here you have the variable in front of your eyes so you don't forget it.

Comment: No, handling an exception (or returning an error code) is not a crash - unless the error/exception is logically fatal or you choose not to handle it. You still have the _opportunity_ to handle the error case, _without_ having to explicitly check at every step whether an error occurred previously

Comment: @AdrianMaire In almost every application I work on, I would vastly prefer a crash over silently continuing. I work on business-critical software where taking some bad output and continuing to operate on it could result in a lot of money lost. If correctness is crucial and crashing acceptable, then exceptions have a very large advantage here.

Comment: @Useless: `No, handling an exception (or returning an error code) is not a crash `.. but NOT handling an exception is usually a crash. And is very easy to (forgot ) NOT handle an exception or a return code. It seem that the concept of explicit/implicit error from the user code is not obvious.

Comment: @AdrianMaire - I think it is much much harder to forget to handle an exception that your method of forgetting an if statement... Besides - the main benefit of exceptions is which layer handles them. You may wish to let a system exception bubble up further to show an application level error message but handle situations that you know about at a lower level. If you are using third party libraries or other developers code this is really the only choice...

Comment: @Milney: ` I think it is much much harder to forget to handle an exception` Why? It is something hidden in a binary file somewhere. If not documented properly, you don't even know it exists.

Comment: @AdrianMaire 'It is harder to forget to handle an exception' Because the program is not allowed to continue operating once an exception is thrown unless it is caught. If you forget to catch that exception, the program crashes. It isn't that it is harder to write a program that doesn't catch exceptions, it is that it becomes obvious when you do (because it crashes.)

Comment: cont... In general for a given operation you have three possible results: correct output; incorrect output; and no output (crash). As the consumer relying on the output of the program, if you rate these in order of desirability, I'd be surprised if you came up with anything other than: 1 correct; 2 no output; 3. incorrect. I never want to be handed incorrect results, because further work on those results can't help but continue to be incorrect. Forgetting to handle exceptions leads to a crash: the second best outcome. Forgetting to check an error code leads to the worst.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor: That is exactly the mistake: to think that an exception will throw during testing phase. Have you easy way to test each memory bad_alloc, disk full, network disconnection, etc.? No. Read again `This has two consequences`. Most throws are not managed by programmers because they never happens during development.

Comment: @Adrian No mistake, you seem to have misread what I wrote or missed the second half of it. My whole point isn't that the exception will throw during testing/development and that the developers will realize they need to handle them. The point is that the consequence of a completely unhandled exception in production is preferable to the consequence of an unchecked error code. if you miss the error code, _you get and continue to use wrong results._ If you miss the exception, the application crashes and doesn't continue to run, you get _no results_ not _wrong results_. (cont.)

Comment: (cont) to put simply: if you throw exceptions to signal errors, it is harder to write a program that gives incorrect results.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor: Now I got what you said. You are right than most of the case, an unchecked/wrong result is worse. When it refer to GUI, however, I would state the reverse: you prefer a dialog not working than the system crashing.